# Performance of filter expression for matching all files : * vs. *.*

Tags: file-search

Let's say I need to provide a filter to match all files in a given filesystem, not necessarily in linux, but also for matching all files in an IDE with huge code base that supports regex based filtering. Is there any significant performance difference between using

> *

vs.

> ***. ***

Note: Please ignore the extra space in above expression, posting it without space makes it a dot for some reason.

Assuming all files have extensions, these expressions are one and the same. However, I would like to know if any one of it outperform the other especially when there are huge number of files to match.

Comment: `*` can match "nothing". `.` requires at least one character to be present. While it doesn't make much sense (and probably isn't legal in any filesystem) to have a file with a "null" name, why make a more complicated pattern if the simple one does what you awnt?

Comment: In most cases by far, your time will be spend looking up the names of the files, i. e. in I/O-operations. Matching of the names to the wildcards will be so fast as to be virtually zero in comparison to any I/O operation. Thus: no, do not expect relevant differences in performance.

Comment: I built upon the above comment in my answer below. One outperformes the other, but both are blazingly fast.

Answer (score 1):

Performance will vary from one regex engine to the next, so we can't really say for sure. As Bernhard [shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453834/2295834), the I/O is more expensive than either regex.

The regular expressions you would really use, however, would be these:

`.*` - Matches any string with 0 or more characters.

and

`.*\..*` - Matches a string with 0 or more characters, followed by a period, followed by a string with 0 or more characters.

If all you're going to do is put this in regex-compliant search bars in file explorers/browsers and IDEs, then you should just use `.*`. As Marc B noted in a comment, you should prefer the simpler one. If for no other reason, it's easier to understand. If I came across the second one...I would be wondering what the original intent was. `.*` is also kind of special, and there's potential that the regex engine you're using has optimized it.

However, if you're thinking of using these regexes on the command line or programmatically: tread carefully. `.*` will match several things that could be bad on Linux and Mac OS X:

- The `.` directory - may lead to infinite recursion depending on what you're doing.
- The `..` directory - will lead whatever you're running up to `/`. If paired with a recursive option/flag this means that whatever you're running will touch the entire filesystem.
- Hidden files - hidden files start with a `.`

And that's just the beginning. Be *very* careful when using regular expressions that capture a wide net of strings. But like I said, in search bars you should be fine with `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

I my comment I claim, that the computational time of matching regex will almost always be lower than the I/O reading the file system. Here is an example to see, how fast regexes can be. I am using some small Desktop i5 @3.1Ghz 8MB RAM - not a number cruncher computer but not bad. Many People will use something similar. I am using R, an interpreted language where measuring time is easy.

A random sample of 1 million filenames consisting of 8 letters point 3 letters as in old DOS times. The code is:

```
n <- 1000000
#simulate n filenames of 8 letters dot 3 letters
filenames <- replicate(n, paste0(paste0(sample(LETTERS, 8),collapse=""),
       ".", paste0(sample(LETTERS, 3), collapse=""), collapse=""))
```

I used an automatic Translation from "*. *" which gave the following regex:

```
> glob2rx("*.*")
[1] "^.*\\."
```

Without further optimization, I grepped all 1 million filenames whilst taking the time:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  search = grep("^.*\\.",filenames ,value=TRUE))
```

And this is the result:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 search 368.1657 373.883 392.9093 376.7103 415.4723 477.3519   100
```

Out of 100 times grepping all filenames the longest duration was 477 MS, the mean duration was 393 ms. Now imagine, how long your file system will take to read 1 million filenames and it will take less than 0.4 seconds in an interpreted language to make a copy of these filenames with regex control.

The automatic Translation for "*" was "^". Now, this was considerably faster:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 search 166.866 167.8187 181.0547 169.0102 171.7741 236.9923   100
```

2.2 times faster. But who cares, whether such a task takes 180 ms or 400 ms, when you are waiting for file IO and a GUI to handle those amounts of data.

---

For a more realistic 10,000 filenames, the results are

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
        star 0.840248 0.844221 0.8615701 0.847531 0.867064  1.383529  1000
 stardotstar 2.702499 2.709452 2.7827241 2.751498 2.787914 12.248153  1000
```

So a single star is evaluated in under a millisecond and the Translation of star-dot-star is evaluated in less than 3 milliseconds. That is factor 3.1 faster for the single star. Well...